# Need Help in Iteration of Generic

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        Car car1 = new Car();  
        car1.Make  = "Oldsmobile";  
        car1.Model = "Cultas Supreme";  

        Car car2 = new Car();  
        car2.Make  = "GEO";
        car2.Model = "Prism";  

        Dictionary<string, Car> myDicitionary = new Dictionary<string, Car>();
        myDicitionary.Add(car1.Model, car1);
        myDicitionary.Add(car2.Model, car2);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Car> CAR in myDicitionary)
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key,CAR.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Car 
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }       
}
```

output Result

> Cultas Supreme-- Collection.Programe+Car Prism--
>
> Collection.Program+Car

but why it Doest not show the value of Car instead of Collection.Programe+Car`

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean, but I think you meant to override `ToString` in `Car`.

Comment: Because you try to output an object of the type "Car". Since you didn't override the `ToString()` method, it will use the default (object) ToString-method.

Answer (score 3):

The default `.ToString()` method returns the name of the object. If you want the method to return something else, you need to override it:

```
class Car
{
   // same as before

   public override string ToString()
   {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Make, Model);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are outputting this:

> Cultas Supreme-- Collection.Programe+Car

This happens because you write:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key,CAR.Value);
```

Since `CAR.Value` is going to be the `Car` instance, when you write this out, it will call the `Car.ToString()` method to turn the `Car` into a string.  Since you did not override `ToString()` in your `Car` class, it just outputs the name of the class:  *Collection.Programe+Car* (since Car is a nested class in Programe).

To get this to output an appropriate value, you should either write out the specific value in car (change `CAR.Value` to `CAR.Value.Make` or similar), or provide an appropriate implementation of `ToString()` within your Car class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either override the `ToString()` method (as demonstrated in other posted answers), or else retrieve the property you want to print from the `Car` object (available through the `Value` property of the `KeyValuePair<string,Car>`):

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Car> CAR in myDicitionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key, CAR.Value.Make);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key,CAR.Value.Make)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go to the Car class and override the `ToString` method of the car.  In that method have it write out whatever you feel the best string representation of a car is.

You could also (or additionally) change `Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key,CAR.Value);` to `Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Key,CAR.Value.Make);` to display just the car's make when you print it.

Comment: many thank to Dave Hanson and all other guy who give me response. now I can understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-- {1}", CAR.Value.Model,CAR.Value.Make);
```

CAR refers to KeyValuePair(String model, CAR car)
CAR.KEY refer to model
CAR.Value refer to CAR
CAR.VALUE.MAKE refer to CAR.MAKE
CAR.VALUE.Model refer to CAR.Model

As mentioned in other answers, you can also override ToString()  in Car class

```
public override ToString()
{
   return String.Format("{0}---{1}", Model, Make);
}
```

After overriding ToString() you can use car.ToString

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Car> CAR in myDicitionary)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(CAR.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to override the ToString() method on Car

Its showing 
Cultas Supreme - which is a string Correct
Collection.Program + Car  which is the Value of the Car object

try addign this to your car object... and you'll understand that Console.Writeline when given and object outputs the objects to string method.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return this.Make
}
```